# Is it possible to cite a whole album under the CC license

Tags: creative-commons

I want to add a whole album of images to my homepage. All photos stand under the same [CC license](https://creativecommons.org). Is there a way to cite the album instead of each image individually?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using images that weren't created by you, that were all licensed by their original owner under CC? Or do you mean you are using images that were created by you, and want to license them all the same?

Comment: I am using images NOT created by me. All the photos are licensed by the original owner under CC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to cite the album instead of each image individually?

According to [Best practices for attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Best_practices_for_attribution#Title.2C_Author.2C_Source.2C_License) at the Creative Commons Wiki,

> A good rule of thumb is to use the acronym **TASL**, which stands for Title, Author, Source, License.
>
> **Title** - What is the name of the material?
>
> If a title was provided for the material, include it. Sometimes a title is not provided; in that case, don't worry about it.
>
> **Author** - Who owns the material?
>
> Name the author or authors of the material in question. Sometimes, the licensor may want you to give credit to some other entity, like a company or pseudonym. In rare cases, the licensor may not want to be attributed at all. In all of these cases, just do what they request.
>
> **Source** - Where can I find it?
>
> Since you somehow accessed the material, you know where to find it. Provide the source of the material so others can, too. Since we live in the age of the Internet, this is usually a URL or hyperlink where the material resides.
>
> **License** - How can I use it?
>
> You are obviously using the material for free thanks to the CC license, so make note of it. Don't just say the material is Creative Commons, because that says nothing about how the material can actually be used. Remember that there are six different CC licenses; which one is the material under? Name and provide a link to it, eg. http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/ for CC BY.

Generally, if the use of the image can support citing TASL under it or near it, then do it. If it's not feasible to do so (for instance, it's part of the page background), then placing TASL attribution in a footer is appropriate, or perhaps (least good option) in a [colophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colophon_(publishing)).

So to your question, do the images have individual **titles**? Were the images all created by one individual, where the images are available from the same source (i.e., same URL)? If those are both true, then arguably attributing TASL for the album is okay. But if not, the resources have distinct TASL, so they should be attributed as such.